# plotting concave objects with mayavi or vtk

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, vtk, mayavi

I am just getting started using mayavi in python, and don't know too much about programming 3d graphics. I want to plot a concave surface/object but when I try it comes out being connected like this:

[image: whats happening]

you can't see by the picture but it is formed by parallel planes(not what I intended either)

when I'm trying to plot a structure with this shape:

[image: what i'm trying to plot]

So here's what I do to get the points and plot:

```
#extract the black in the image
x,y,z = np.where(quest == 0)
#make z1,z2 the right size(y*0) and value(+12)
z1 = y*0
z2 = y*0+12
x,y,z1,z2= np.atleast_2d(x,y,z1,z2)
#duplicate the shape at z1 and z2
x = np.concatenate((x,x))
y = np.concatenate((y,y))
z = np.concatenate((z1,z2))
#plot the mesh
mlab.mesh(x,y,z)
mlab.show()
```

I've noticed that the order of your data points matter for using mesh, because it will draw a line from each consecutive point.

Is there an easier way to do this that somehow organize my points?

Also is there a way to make the shape fill the area between points?

All help is appreciated, Thanks

Followup Questions:

Is there a better 3d library for python that would serve this purpose?

I'm looking into doing it with vtk, but the same problem of cutting out the concave portion of the question mark like this:

[image: Same problem in vtk]

The much longer code for this is:

```
#create the points
points = vtk.vtkPoints()
for i, j in zip(x,y):
    points.InsertNextPoint(i,j,0)
#create a polygon
polygon = vtk.vtkPolygon()
polygon.GetPointIds().SetNumberOfIds(len(x))
for i in range(len(x)):
    polygon.GetPointIds().SetId(i,i)
#add it to a cell array
polygons = vtk.vtkCellArray()
polygons.InsertNextCell(polygon)
#make the poly data
polyData = vtk.vtkPolyData()
polyData.SetPoints(points)
polyData.SetPolys(polygons)
#set up the window
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInput(polyData
actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
rWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
rWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
rWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
rWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(rWindow)
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderer.SetBackground(.5,.3,.31)
rWindow.Render()
rWindowInteractor.Start()
```

Comment: There is nothing magic about convexity - a mesh is a mesh, exactly how you define it. It seems like you are getting the coordinates of the black pixels... then what? How do you want the mesh to be defined over these point? You have to specify that to VTK (in the construction of the polygons), then it will be drawn properly.

Answer (score 3):

This post is more one year old but It may still be useful to other.

I had the same problem and I resolved it by using a [`vtkTriangleFilter`](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkTriangleFilter.html#details). This filter converts input polygons in triangle, more understandable for OpenGL.

Here is a quick script where I create a concave shape ("looks like" an elephant) and I provide a boolean to filter the shape or not at beginning.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from vtk import *

# switch to False if you don't want to filter the shape
FILTER = True

# x and y values of points to create a concave shape
x = [-2.25032, -3.04773, -3.06125, -2.69633, -2.52063, -2.16923, -1.72322, -1.47994, -1.85837, -1.04745, -0.68253, 1.25018, 1.81783, 3.20992, 2.15571, 1.99353, 2.72336, 3.35859, 3.57483, 3.60186, 3.69647, 4.18303, 4.29115, 3.87217, 2.87203, 2.07462, 1.43939, 1.10151, 0.912292, 0.466283, 1.27721, 0.723076, -1.22315]

y = [-1.3371, -0.671689, 0.094162, 0.081607, -0.4457, -0.960452, -0.797238, 0.0313873, 1.43754, 1.76397, -0.00627746, -0.295041, 1.42498, 1.36221, -0.39548, -1.21155, -1.57564, -1.57564, -1.03578, -0.47081, 0.244821, 0.169492, -0.822348, -1.98996, -2.7307, -2.96924, -3.20778, -2.89391, -2.56748, -2.12806, -1.93974, -1.65097, -1.60075]


# creation of the source
positions = zip(x, y)

triFilter = vtkTriangleFilter()

pts = vtkPoints()
polygon = vtkPolygon()
polygon.GetPointIds().SetNumberOfIds(len(positions))

for k, l in enumerate(positions):
    pts.InsertNextPoint(float(l[0]), float(l[1]), 1)
    polygon.GetPointIds().SetId(k, k)

polygons = vtkCellArray()
polygons.InsertNextCell(polygon)

polygonPolyData = vtkPolyData()
polygonPolyData.SetPoints(pts)
polygonPolyData.SetPolys(polygons)

# let's filter the polydata
triFilter.SetInputData( polygonPolyData)
triFilter.Update()

polygonPolyDataFiltered = triFilter.GetOutput()

# map it
mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()

if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5:

    if FILTER:
        mapper.SetInput(polygonPolyDataFiltered)
    else:
        mapper.SetInput(polygonPolyData)
else:
    if FILTER:
        mapper.SetInputData(polygonPolyDataFiltered)
    else:
        mapper.SetInputData(polygonPolyData)

# render it

actor =  vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

ren = vtkRenderer()
ren.AddActor(actor)

renwin = vtkRenderWindow()
renwin.AddRenderer(ren)

iren = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renwin)

iren.SetInteractorStyle(vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera())
iren.Initialize()
iren.Start()
```